# Why is this question non constructive?

Tags: discussion, support, closed-questions, specific-question

Why is this question non constructive? The question is specific. It doesn't solicit debates or arguments. **An app either sends to Facebook and Twitter or it doesn't**. Isn't this consiered like a fact?

https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/42505/how-to-send-to-twitter-and-facebook-at-same-time-tweetdeck-replacement

Comment: _but this question will likely solicit debate, arguments, **polling**, or extended discussion._ Also, see [this meta discussion](http://meta.webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/1000/double-standards-on-web-app-recommendation-questions/1003#1003) on App recommendations

Comment: How is that? If someone says app A does what you want, you think someone will come and say "no it doesn't", argues & debates?

Comment: More on the lines of "App A good", "You nuts? App A sucks, App B is good", "App C is waay better".

Comment: It's not constructive because it's basically asking for a list. Every answer would be equally valid. Those are not the kinds of questions that are good for Stack Exchange. See also: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/

Comment: @Sathya The question is not asking which is better or grade the app.

Comment: @Al That's the part I don't like about StackExchange. Whether it's a list of 1 or a list of 6 or a list of 0 (seems it doesn't exist), the answers would be beneficial to the asker than not allowing this kind of questions. The asker can pick one, be satisfied and move on with life. I don't find this question the same type as one in that post. It's not about x vs y,

Comment: FWIW: stripped down a bit, your question would be a duplicate of [this one](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/21129/post-to-twitter-facebook-and-blogs-in-one-app). You might also be interested in [Slant](http://www.slant.co/).

Comment: @Shog9: A question is not a duplicate of another question when the answers to the old question do not apply anymore. Tweetdeck doesn't do it anymore. Posterous is closing this month. I will check Slant.

Answer (score 2):

Essentially what you're asking for are suggestions for app replacements.

These type of questions fall better on sites geared for that such as [Slant](http://www.slant.co/) and [AlternativeTo.net](http://alternativeto.net/software/tweetdeck/).

As a general test, if your question would be perfectly in line with either of these two sites, it's most likely not constructive and ill-fit for a Stack Exchange site.